# how to add custom fields in page

Tags: themes, custom-field

I am still new to Wordpress and I want to insert a featured content gallery into a Wordpress page. I tried to do it myself, but it wanted me to use custom fields.

Where can I add custom fields, is there any coding required? or do I just enter the value into custom fields text box? I want to add and then use custom fields for images in my featured content gallery, can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

> **Edit: Came back on this post much later but I am updating this with more correct information.**

The following code will allow you to display the value of a custom field anywhere in your theme or plugin, as long as you are getting the correct post ID to pass to it. You would need to put `global $post;` inside your function in order to get the post ID from the [global `$post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:CharlesClarkson/Global_Variables) variable. If you have other means of getting the ID (such as [get_the_ID()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=get_the_id&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID&ei=Yyu4TqW7HYGksQLQ1bjCAw&usg=AFQjCNEdsaKQ9axsON6Myn3DY7pK29L6nw&sig2=O-f8BP6gvH5gClhmrHhMqQ) function), you can just use that in place of `$post->ID`.

```
<?php
    echo get_post_meta(
        $post->ID,
        'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME',
        true
    );
?>
```

---

#### Old notes:

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME_HERE', true); ?>`

This is the code you need. :)

Just put this in your theme file anywhere you want the custom value to be displayed inside of the loop, of course when you are posting, fill out the custom field text boxes accordingly.

Comment: just put it anywhere in the theme file i want to use.. or put in into exact location

Comment: @BeginnerPogrammer If my answer was sufficient, can you mark it as best answer so that it doesn't haunt the website as "Unanswered"? Thanks.